# What is the best way to download big files form MEGA.nz?

Tags: firefox, online-storage, firefox-extensions, mega

Cloud storage service MEGA.nz has a web interface that can be accessed from a web browser, like Firefox. If a user tries to access his cloud storage through a browser and tries to download a file to his local computer, the file is first downloaded into the computer's memory, and only after that it can be saved on a hard drive.

The problem arises with large files, 1GB and above, because first the browser tries to occupy more than 1 GB of the computer's memory, and then an "Out of memory" exception is fired and the downloading is interrupted.

In addition to the web interface, MEGA.nz is providing a browser extension that used to solve this problem by saving files directly to a computer's hard drive and not to the memory. But recent updates to the service rendered former versions of the extension unusable and the new version downloads the files to the memory first, like the web interface does without the extension.

Essentially this makes it almost impossible or very difficult for people to access their files that are bigger than 1 GB.

**What is the best and easiest way to download large files from MEGA.nz?**

(I am using Firefox 56.0.1 with MEGA extension v. 3.17.2 on Windows 7 x64)

Comment: If you are getting “out of memory” exceptions then increase the amount of virtual memory your system has.  As for methods of downloading files from a cloud service, this question isn’t on topic here at SU, so I voted to migrate it.